# shinydashboard: how to place the menusubitem outside a hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, shinydashboard

I am using shinydashboard and in the dashboardSidebar I need to select some elements in a menusubitem . When I select more than one element in a selectInput with the control or shift button a new chrome page is opening. When I try straight in Rstudio there is no problem.

It looks that dashboard places the menusubitem inside a hyperlink (suggested by Dean Attali).

How could I avoid this reaction?

Thanks

```
    shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(skin = 'blue',
        dashboardHeader(title = 'reprexes', titleWidth = 450),
        dashboardSidebar(width = 350,

            tags$style('.fa-table {color:#33cc33}'),     
            tags$style('.table2 {color:#0099ff}'),     

            sidebarMenu(width = 350,
            menuSubItem( p(''),
            icon = NULL),
            menuItem('Example1', icon = icon('table'),
            menuSubItem(uiOutput('col_sel'),icon = NULL)

            )
            ) # sidebarMenu
        ), # dashboardSidebar


        dashboardBody(    
            tabBox(width = '500px',

            tabPanel('Instructions', 
            h4('Plots') )   # tabPanel
            )   # tabBox
        )
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
        output$col_sel <- renderUI({
        cn <-c('New York', 'Paris', 'Pekin')
        selectInput('var_1', 'Select the variables', 
        choices  = cn,
        selected = 1,
        multiple=TRUE, selectize=FALSE)
        })
    }
)
```